# How to know that Java is installed in a Linux system?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu. How to know if Java is installed ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your terminal type `java -version` or just `javac` if it returns something, then you've java installed. Otherwise, there is also the possibility that the path variables do not contain the java path. So use  `locate jdk` or `locate java` to see if you have the java binary. Don't forget to run updatedb if you are using `locate` for the first time.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to run `which java` or `java -version`.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers seems pretty OBVIOUS..!! (only if you have to check JAVA)

For checking any package (whether it is installed or not), u can do the following :

> sudo aptitude search *packageName*

It will get you a list of Packages (that you wanted to find out, whether installed or not). In the list, on the left hand side, (*the key to the Your question*) , there lies a small Alphabet denoting whether the corresponding package is already installed on your system or not.

For example, for java, you will do like :

> sudo aptitude search jdk

and you will get something like :

> i A default-jdk
>
> i A default-jdk-doc
>
> i A openjdk-6-doc i A
>
> i A openjdk-6-jdk
>
> i A openjdk-6-jre v
>
> p openjdk-6-jre-shark
>
> p openjdk-6-jre-zero
>
> p openjdk-6-source

Now the "**i**" on the left shows that it is installed.

CHEERS..!!

Answer (score 3):

```
java -v
```

should do the job aswell.

Comment: If it's on the `$PATH`.